# I want solution to the problem of installing Odoo 15 code sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, odoo-15

```
raise Exception("Version mismatch: this is the 'cffi' package version %s, located in %r.  When we import the top-level '_cffi_backend' extension module, we get version %s, located in %r.  The two versions should be equal; check your installation." % (
      Exception: Version mismatch: this is the 'cffi' package version 1.15.1, located in '/tmp/pip-build-env-xgw_0l3c/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cffi/api.py'.  When we import the top-level '_cffi_backend' extension module, we get version 1.15.0, located in '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'.  The two versions should be equal; check your installation.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried to install Odoo again for this problem, but it failed

Answer (score 0):

Solved same error here. Uninstall first with pip:

```
pip3 uninstall cffi
```

And after install with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-cffi
```

After this you can continue with:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade only pip:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```